# LINQ get columns in result by which query was grouped by

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem with getting grouped columns in LINQ.

My class:

```
public class DTO_CAORAS
{    
    public int? iORAS_KEY_CON { get; set; }
    public int? iMERC_KEY {get;set;}
    public double? decD_ORAS_QUA {get;set;}        
}
```

LINQ query:

```
var results =
    from oras in listCAORAS_Delivered
    group oras by new
    {
      oras.iORAS_KEY_CON,
      oras.iMERC_KEY
    }
    into orasGroup
    select new
    {
      decD_ORAS_QUA = orasGroup.Sum(x => x.decD_ORAS_QUA)
    };
```

List `results` is filled only with one column - `decD_ORAS_QUA`. I don't know how to get columns, by which query is grouped - `IORAS_KEY_CON` and `iMERC_KEY`? I would like to fill `results` with iORAS_KEY_CON, iMERC_KEY and decD_ORAS_QUA.

Input data:

```
+---------------+-----------+---------------+
| iORAC_KEY_CON | iMERC_Key | decD_ORAS_QUA |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+
|            1  |      888  |             1 |
|            1  |      888  |             2 |
|            1  |      888  |             4 |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Desired output:

```
+---------------+-----------+---------------+
| iORAC_KEY_CON | iMERC_Key | decD_ORAS_QUA |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+
|            1  |      888  |             7 |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Question is unclear. Currently you group by two columns and get the sum of the third. What do you want to do? Please show some example data and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To also show the keys:

```
var results = from oras in listCAORAS_Delivered
              group oras by new { oras.iORAS_KEY_CON, oras.iMERC_KEY } into g
              select new DTO_CAORAS {
                  iORAS_KEY_CON = g.Key.iORAS_KEY_CON,
                  iMERC_KEY = g.Key.iMERC_KEY,
                  decD_ORAS_QUA = g.Sum(x => x.decD_ORAS_QUA)
              };
```

As you are only grouping one column you can also:

```
var results = from oras in listCAORAS_Delivered
              group oras.decD_ORAS_QUA by new { oras.iORAS_KEY_CON, oras.iMERC_KEY } into g
              select new DTO_CAORAS {
                  iORAS_KEY_CON = g.Key.iORAS_KEY_CON,
                  iMERC_KEY = g.Key.iMERC_KEY,
                  decD_ORAS_QUA = g.Sum()
              };
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert results to List<DTO_CAORAS> ?